# Filtering file using reg exp and concatenate certain lines together (command-prompt)

Tags: windows, vbscript, command-prompt

I have to filter a text file filter.tmp containing two types of lines, this shows the difference:

```
findstr /r "^[0-9][0-9]*.*$" filter.tmp > filter-numbers.tmp
findstr /r "^[^0-9][^0-9]*.*$" filter.tmp > filter-text.tmp
```

What I need to do is to append lines containing text together like this and if line does contain number just put it to output file:

```
IF "current line" contains text THEN
previous line = concatenate "previous line" + "/" + "current line"
ELSE
echo "previous line" >> filter.out
echo "current line" >> filter.out
```

filter.tmp contains something like:

```
Hello
World
Foo
Bar
45: this is some line
Trouble
with code
66: another line
```

filter.out should look like:

```
Hello/World/Foo/Bar
45: this is some line
Trouble/with code
66: another line
```

I realize, this is very simple, but I just can not get it working. As I am thinking about it, it would be much easier to use C++....

Comment: I think a C++ solution might be more complex than the batch file. It could be easier to understand, though.

Comment: Bali C, I wanted to but there was no IDE installed on workstation and I just had limited user rights so I could not install any

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a quite verbatim translation of your pseudocode and your regexes, based on the assumption that »contains numbers« really means »starts with two digits« (which is what your regexes show):

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion
set Prev=
for /f "delims=" %%x in (filter.tmp) do (
    set "Line=%%x"
    if "!Line:~0,2!" GEQ "00" if "!Line:~0,2!" LEQ "99" (
        if not "!Prev!"=="" (>>filter.out echo !Prev!)
        >>filter.out echo !Line!
        set Prev=
    ) else (
        if "!Prev!"=="" (set "Prev=!Line!") else (set "Prev=!Prev!/!Line!")
    )
)
if not "!Prev!"=="" (>>filter.out echo !Prev!)
```

This uses several things. First of all, we need delayed expansion which enables us to manipulate environment variables within the loop. Then we iterate over the lines in the file with `for /f`. Note that this will skip empty lines in the file, but you cannot avoid that. Inside the `for /f` loop the variable `Line` holds the current line and `Prev` the previous one (if there has been a previous one). I swapped the `then` and `else` branches of the condition since numbers at the start of the line are easier to check for than non-numbers.

With the `echo` you'll notice that I moved the redirection to the start of the line; this is to prevent trailing numbers in `Prev` or `Line` from having an effect on the redirection (and also to avoid trailing spaces).

If you're not adverse to PowerShell, you can use the following:

```
$(switch -Regex -File filter.tmp {
    '^\D'    { if ($prev) { $prev += "/$_" } else { $prev = $_ } }
    '^\d{2}' { if ($pref) {$prev}; $_; $prev = '' }
}
if ($prev) { $prev }
) | Set-Content filter.out
```

Comment: Thanks Joye, there is just problem with echo, where variable is not set and it prints that default echo message in filter.out
I fixed it with ... "echo. !Prev!" but this prints blank lines. So I will need to think of removing them. 
Powershell was actually my first idea, but I do not have rights to install anything....

Comment: Should work now. I guess that was the case when the first line was one starting with a number, right?